# Unmet dependencies in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, apt

While executing some apt install commands in Ubuntu I get the output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvinfer-dev : Depends: libnvinfer-headers-dev (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but 8.6.1.6-1+cuda12.0 is to be installed
 libnvinfer-plugin-dev : Depends: libnvinfer-headers-plugin-dev (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but 8.6.1.6-1+cuda12.0 is to be installed
 libnvparsers-dev : Depends: libnvparsers8 (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Next I try to install libnvparsers8=8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8 manually:

```
sudo apt install libnvparsers8=8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8
```

And this install succeeds!

```
apt list --installed | grep libnvparsers8

libnvparsers8/unknown,now 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 8.6.1.6-1+cuda12.0]
```

But why apt didn't install this dependency automatically?